# Same Auto Incremental ID Should be insert into Insert Query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need some help from you people. I don't know It's possible or not.

In PHP, When I insert new query into Database ID value will be auto increment. I have one more variable in that Query, which is `parentID`.

When Run the query, `parentID` should be equal to the auto Incremental ID.

I tried `mysqli_insert_id($conn);` this function. Get last ID. Add one with that value then assign that value to `parentID` and then insert into database.

But Some kind of time it may be give Isolate problem. So any one guide to provide some other solution to avoid Isolate problem. Isolate means when I try to insert, I got last ID from db. Now assign that value to `ParendID` variable. And then I try to insert Into DB. Assume it may take few minutes. Within that few minutes some other guys may insert their own regards. That time my last ID will be differed. So I Insert with wrong `parendID` value.

Please any one help me to solve this problem..!!

```
<?php
  //My connection 
  $last_id = $conn->insert_id; //get last ID from DB
  $parent_id = $last_id + 1;

  $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email, ParentID)
           VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com', $parent_id)";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully.";
  } else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }

?>
```

First I get LastID and then add One with that value. Then I'll insert Into DB. Instead of this method, In query itself,  Directly, can give any other possible solution to assign parent ID equal to current ID of the field?

Comment: Totally lost with your question, do you have any code? I think you are asking to put the auto id into more than one column?

Comment: You can get correct last inserted id only after insert in same connection to DB

Comment: ya thanks any other way?

Comment: Without code we cant help you

Comment: Ya I have added..!!! Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the help of the triggers, 
all you need to do is copy the new value of the id into the parentID "AFTER" insertion.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_parentID 
AFTER INSERT ON MyGuests
FOR EACH ROW SET 
NEW.ParentId = NEW.ID;
```

Code should look something like this (THIS ONE IS NOT TESTED)

Comment: whether this is not give any Isolate problem?

Comment: Isolate problems? 
Not sure about this particular code snippet, But this is how it's supposed to be done. Every time you add a new record, it automatically populates the last column.

Comment: If some one added new column after I added in db, this code will give my ID or Last ID which was updated by others? Please assume that within a secounds there will be 10 records added in DB.

Comment: NEW in MySQL is a pointer to the current record added. 
The trigger will be executed **FOR EACH** insertion, so the value of new should be atomic to each transaction. that's what the MySQL manual says [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)